# How to pass a selected file name in delete message box in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using ext.js sencha. In that if I want to delete a selected file then in alert message box how to pass the file name?  I want a java script code for this.

Comment: This would be a good time to read [ask] and [mcve]. Your question is lacking far too many details for anyone to help

Answer (score 1):

Am not getting what exactly what you want but i think you want something like following as i understand.

```
$(document).on('click','.btn_delete',function(){

    var fullPath = document.getElementById('file_id').value;
    var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
    var filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);

    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete..??"+filename))
      {  
            alert(filename);  

      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bhava. But I am not using jquery. Only javascript.